# What did Mike write in Tina's birthday card

Tags: better-call-saul

In the first episode of the 4<sup>th</sup> season of Better Call Saul, Mike is asked to sign a birthday card for Tina, what did Mike write to her? I can't understand the writing.

[image: greeting card]

Comment: However illegible this message may be, I love how he makes the _H_

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Mike writes the following:

> Reach for the
>   stars!
>   Barry H

It's just a generic message, there's no real interesting information/easter egg here.

Comment: Are Mike and Barry the same person?

Comment: @NogShine Not quite following your question. Mike is Mike. Barry is either the name of the person whose card he stole (I seem to remember that he is called Barry (revealed when he calls work to say he's late) but I'm not sure anymore), or Mike just invented the name on the spot  since he was undercover and the guys don't know him anyway.

Comment: Yes, he drained Barry's car battery and stole his card from his briefcase

Answer (score 2):

> Reach for the stars! Barry H

This phase is actually a bit odd or ironic, because this is NOT common phrase seen on an adult birthday card for a women already in the workforce.

It's something that would be more common on a child's birthday card, someone graduating from high school or collage, and/or someone changing directions in life, as "reaching for the stars" is about embracing the future and hopefully finding what you are looking for. It's geared more towards a shift or change.

With that being said, you could apply this phrase in a few ways

1. Mike was being facetious towards Tina, because she's probably stuck at her job and has been in the workforce for a while.
2. He wrote it thinking about his granddaughter and her future, which is one reason why he has taken this job.
3. There is an irony in this phrase if you apply to Mike himself (like as if Mike was really writing it to himself), because he has just switched directions in his own life by taking this job and by being optimistic about his own future, when most viewers already know Mike's fate.
4. *Better Call Saul* is shifting this season, as it gets closer to *Breaking Bad*.